# how to animate when click class or id using css3 ?

Tags: jquery, css

i am learning css3 now i can run the animation wen the window open, but i need if i click any class or id then only it will animate please any one help me

```
<html>

        <div id="test"  class="target animate">Try me</div>

            <div class="fff" style="width:100px;height:100px;background:#4AB72F"><h3>click here</h3></div>




            <style>


            #test {
                width:160px;
                height:200px;
                margin: 100px;
                background:#68C6F2;

                -webkit-transition: all 1s ease-in-out;
                -moz-transition: all 1s ease-in-out;    
                -ms-transition: all 1s ease-in-out;
                -o-transition: all 1s ease-in-out;    
                transition: all 1s ease-in-out;
            }

            #test.animate {
                -moz-animation-name: test;
                -moz-animation-duration: 1s;
            }

            @keyframes test{
                from { -moz-transform: translateX(-100%) scale(.1) rotateY(-50deg);}
            }

            </style>
</html>
```

i am using firefox browser, nicely working this but i need if i click any class or id then only it will animate, any one assist me please (or you can tell me like using jquery it will very helpful for me  ) thanks

Comment: you want to object to animate at runtime?

Answer (score 0):

I had answered this for other person too. i guess your promblem is also same.

well i don't think it is easy to create dynamic **`@keyframes they are inflexible because they must be hard-coded.`**

Transitions are a little easier to work with, as they can gracefully respond to any CSS changes performed by JavaScript.

However, the complexity that CSS transitions can give you is pretty limited — **`an animation with multiple steps is difficult to achieve.`**

This is a problem that CSS @keyframe animations are meant to solve, **`but they don’t offer the level of dynamic responsiveness that transitions do.`**

but these links might help you

[Link1](http://www.joelambert.co.uk/morf/)  : a tool that generates a @-webkit-keyframe animation with many tiny steps. This opens the door to an unlimited selection of easing formula.

**[Link2](http://rekapi.com/)** This might be very useful.

**[Link3](http://jeremyckahn.github.io/stylie/)** it will be a great help for you to take it as a base as it  provides a UI to create animations and exports it to CSS code.

I guess ****[this](https://github.com/krazyjakee/jQuery-Keyframes)**  solution will definitely work for you. Its is used for dynamic keyframes